# Any possibility to allow only one client connection over openWRT access point?

Tags: connection, openwrt, access-point

Briefly question. As the title shows of, Im searching for a possibility to config openWRT so that only one client connection will be allowed over an access point. Further connection trials should be rejected if one client is connected already. Is this possible by configuration only within the openWRT config?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the `maxassoc` option in the `wifi-iface` section. Setting it to `1` should do it.

The option is described here: https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/wifi/basic#common_options1